# Using SSMA to convert an AccessDatabase

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to convert an AccessDatabase (.accdb) to an SQL Database, using SSMA, and I get some errors:

> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered"

I'm using:
Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 32 bits
SSMA 32 bit
Microsft Access (Office 365) 32 bit
Widowns 10 Home

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). This cannot be answered. Also this site is about programming, so if you have used some code that produces the error you need to show your code. If not this is probably no programming question and therefore off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

When you download  SSMA, you get two shortcuts, one for the x32 bit version, and one for the x64 bit version. If you have the x32 access re-dist, then make sure you launch  the x32 bit version of SSMA.